# How can I change the length of footnote line?

Tags: footnotes, rules, lengths

I need to change the length of the horizontal line that separates text body from footnotes. I want  length of footnote line is as much as width of footnote text.
I can the following codes:

```
    \def\footnoterule{
  \hrule \@width 4in \kern 4\p@}
```

but in this case, length of footnote line is fixed. Can you help me?

Comment: there is no easy way to do that in general, the footnote has been boxed (into a full width box) at the time it is encountered and you do not know which page or pages the footnote text will appear on. Then the rule is added if latex is going to add any footnotes or partial footnotes to the page.

Comment: @Cragfelt No, it's not a duplicate. That question is asking only to change the width of the footnote rule whereas this question is asking to dynamically change the length of the footnote rule depending on the actual footnotes.